Buffering Streams based on adjacent slope using ArcGIS Pro
Elements:
Working with ArcGIS Pro 3.2.2

Line feature Class;  NHD Stream Network
30mx30m raster; Slope calculated from DEM

I have  a stream network that needs a variable buffer.   The buffer width varies based on the slope of the adjacent stream bank.   The stream bank is evaluated using an area weighted average, on each side (along the ground) for 100 feet.
One thought I had was to make the line feature class into a point file (1 point every 10' along each line, attributed with the line Unique ID).   Then use the individual points to sample a moving 10' x 100' moving window and calculate a weighted average slope for the topological left and right side of the stream.
Are there other methods I could use?
